# Python GET request to redirecting URL does not actually redirect me

Tags: python, python-requests

I have an URL that redirects me to an other page, for example:

*https://www.redirector.com/1*
that redirects me to *https://www.redirected.com/1*

I am trying to fetch the ***second*** URL using python requests, I tried doing so using the following code:

```
import requests

rq = requests.get('https://www.redirector.com/1')
for re in rq.history:
    print(re.url)
```

But that doesn't output anything...

Then I tried print the *rq.history* and turns out that was actually an empty list. Is there a way to get the https://www.redirected.com/1 URL besides using the *history* attribute?

Comment: It works properly for me with a test site... try printing out the status code and url of rq first to make sure it's actually redirecting perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

You could view the headers of the response and see if there is a Location header (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Location) and the response code is 3xx. This would be the "low" level approach